# Dynamic struct in C

Tags: c, struct, c-strings

I am trying to read the inputed name, save it in a dynamic struct, add a number at the end if it and count it up. I managed to do the first part, but i cant seem to pass the struct address to the function that should count, nor make the function work.

```
    struct ime_dadoteke
{
    unsigned char *ime;
    unsigned char velikost;
    //this is the struct im working with
};
```

This is the main:

```
 struct ime_dadoteke *ime;
        ime = ime_init();
        int i=1;
        do
        {
            naslednje_ime(ime, i); /*here is the problem with passing the
                                       address. I also tried &ime with parameter
                                       struct ime_dodoteke **ptr. 
                                       I get error cannot convert argument 1
                                       from 'ime_dadoteke *' to 'ime_dodoteke *' */
            i++;
        } while (i <= st_korakov);
```

This is the first function which works:

```
struct ime_dadoteke* ime_init()
{
    int i;
    struct ime_dadoteke *rtn = (struct ime_dadoteke*)malloc(sizeof(struct ime_dadoteke));
    printf_s("Vnesi ime slike.\n");
    rtn->ime =(unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));
    for (i=0; rtn->ime[i-1]!=10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &rtn->ime[i]);
        rtn->ime = (unsigned char*)realloc(rtn->ime, (i+2)*sizeof(unsigned char));

    };

    rtn->ime[i]='\0';
    rtn->velikost = i;
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    return rtn;
};
```

And this is the skeleton of the function that should count the number at the end of the name. I didnt build it yet because i get a problem: pointer to incomplete class is not allowed.

```
void naslednje_ime(struct ime_dodoteke *ptr, int i)
{
    struct ime_dadoteke *ime = ptr;
    ptr /*ptr is underlined (error) */->ime[ptr /*ptr is underlined (error) */->velikost - 1] = '0';
```

};

Also note i created the struct with size of string in it because strlen() doesnt wanna take a non const char. Is there a way around this?

Comment: First order of business is to get used to employing English identifiers. You aren't the only who'll have to read you code, most workplaces and even open-source project are global. Your'e even limiting the amount of people who can read your code without straining themselves on SO, and thus the amount of people that can help you.

Comment: Why is it `ime_dodoteke` in one place but `ime_dadoteke` elsewhere?  Perhaps this is a typo?

Comment: Regardless of language, I recommend making a simpler program that still has your same issue when you go to post on stack overflow. Doing this can also help you solve the problem on your own, as you try to reduce the code down to just the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `pointer to incomplete class is not allowed` means the structure (you told us that referencing members of the `struct ime_dadoteke` via pointer `struct ime_dadoteke *ptr` caused the error message) is not defined in the source unit where `naslednje_ime` is defined. You need to put the struct definition in a header file and include it wherever you use it, also in the file where you define `naslednje_ime`.

Comment: naslednje_ime pototype, ime_init prototype are declared in the same header file where the struct is defined. The main and the file where functions are both have that header icluded.
Also tried defining the struct where the functions are, same effect. And consider this: first function doesnt get this error.

Comment: Nevermind, it was a typo. void naslednje_ime(struct ime_d/o/doteke *ptr, int i). I feel so stupid now. :/

Comment: It's ok, happens to all of us.